# What is storage component in zend framework 2 caching

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I don't know this is a relevant question here. But i got confused a little bit.
Currently i am using zend framework 1. In one of my site i am build cache.

this my current code

```
      $frontend= array(
     ‘lifetime’ => 7200,
     ‘automatic_seralization’ => true
      );

  $backend= array(
     ‘cache_dir’ => ‘./tmp/’,
 );

 $cache = Zend_Cache::factory(‘core’
    ‘File’,
    $fontend,
    $backend
  );
  Zend_Registry::set(‘cache’,$cache);

  $cache = Zend_Registry::get(‘cache’);
  if(!$result = $cache->load(‘mydata’)) {
       echo ‘caching the data…..’;
       $data=array(‘1’,’2’,’3’);
       $cache->save($data, ‘mydata’);
  } else {

   echo ‘retrieving cache data…….’

  }
```

But i am look in to the zf2 some storage factoriesare doing this job. But i cant figure out storage factories. If any one know about this please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: did u try to convert your code and caching configuration to ZF2 first? Or did u try to get any cache adapter or manager instance via servicelocator instead of registry? https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.cache.storage.adapter.html

Comment: Storage factories (like `Zend_Cache` in your code snippet) build cache adapters, which are essentially wrappers for cache drivers (like `$cache` in your snippet). It's similar, only simpler, to getting db adapters. Is this what you wanted to know?